# Rending .ascx in razor cshtml file

Tags: razor

I'm trying to do this in _LayoutPage1.cshtml:

```
@{ this.Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Header.ascx"); }
```

However, since I'm in Razor, intelicense does not show ".RenderPartial" for this.Html.

It works great if I'm in an .aspx page.

Am I missing something?  A @using directive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you need to import `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace into your web.config file under Views directory.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="YOURBASE">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: My layout.cshtml is actually not in my Views folder.  I have it in another folder called Resources.  I tried putting "@using System.Web.Mvc.Html" at the top of the cshtml file, but this.Html.RenderPartial() is still unavailable.  I would think that would fix it.